# Twitter bootstrap navbar collapse works but doesn't return

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap navbar collapses just fine and opens fine but when you try to close the navbar it fails.

I tried replacing the CSS with an older bootstrap file and the same happens. I tried adding the padding to the body like other threads suggested and nothing comes of it. Anyone have an idea?

```
    <!--scripts-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<!--begin nav-->
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></img></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#news">NEWS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#photos">PHOTOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end nav-->
  ........
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

I'll link to the site so the CSS is viewable. [The website is here.](http://ghosteamusic.com)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pulling jQuery into the page in three different places. Twice in the header and once in the footer. Try only one in the footer, just before you pull in Bootstrap script.

Comment: This was the solution! Thank you so much.

Comment: Ah, actually that didn't work. It haulted my own script for that <h1> tag. I had to instead delete the ajax-js script in the footer leaving the two in the header.

Comment: Right, it broke the h1 because that script relies on jQuery and you were loading it in the header, and jquery in the footer. Order matters. You should only need one version of jQuery and if possible, pull it in inside the footer, not the header. Make sure you're pulling in your scripts in the correct order, jQuery first, Boostrap second, then your script.js (which looks like it controls your h1) and then any others.